# Doctrine MongoBundle: Most efficient way to import 28k documents

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-odm

I'm importing 28k documents into a MongoDB using the DoctrineMongoDBBundle (Symfony 2.7.4) by foreach-looping threw the source collection. Although it's working as expected, I was wondering how to optimize the performance. I discovered that importing the first 1000 only takes a blink of an eye, but the import process slows down with every flush. Does it make sense to split the source collection and import e.g. 100 at a time? How often would you flush?

Are there any best practices?

Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: Simple, don't use an ODM for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all depend on available memory and documents size. You can check the size of `unit of work` by `$dm->getUnitOfWork()->size();`. I think you don't detaching documents after flush, that's why everything slow down. Use `clear()` after `flush()` to detach documents from doctrine.

For example, following should persist 100 documents, flush all of them in one operation, detach from doctrine, and repeat this operation for all `$documents`:

```
$batchSize = 100;
$i = 1;
foreach ($documents as $document) {
    $dm->persist($document);
    if (($i % $batchSize) === 0) {
        $dm->flush();
        $dm->clear();
    }
    $i++;
}
$dm->flush();
$dm->clear();
```